# AWK how to print more than one information and redirect all to a text file

Tags: perl, awk

Need help on this
I am creatinga  script that will analyse a file and want to use Awk to print 2 informations in an output txt file
I am able to print the information No one am looking for in my screen but how to print with the same Awk another information (exemple the number of lines of my file analyzed) and output those two information in a file calle test.txt
I tried with this code and code erreor : operator expected

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

if ($#ARGV ==-1)
{
    print "Saisissez un nom de fichier a nalyser \n";
}
else
{
    $fname = $ARGV[0];
    open(FILE, $fname) || die ("cant open \n");
}
while($ligne=<FILE>)
{
    chop ($ligne);
    my ($elemnt1, $ellement2, $element3) = split (/ /, $ligne_);
}
system("awk '{print \$2 > "test.txt"}' $fname");
```

Comment: Why not simply do everything in Perl? It seems rather silly calling `awk` to print out the second column of a file. Perl is a superset of Awk. There is even a command that translate awk scripts into Perl called `a2p` which is probably already on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the quotes on your last line, so `test.txt` is actually in the string passed to `system`.

```
system("awk '{print \$2 > \"test.txt\"}' $fname");
```

### Edit: Adding the number of lines to the same file

The Awk variable `NR` ends up holding the number of lines in the input while the `END` rule is executing. Try this:

```
$outfile = '"test.txt"';
system("awk '{print \$2 > $outfile} END {print NR > $outfile}' $fname");
```

Notes:

1. **Watch out** that `$outfile` doesn't have any funny characters in the name.
2. Unlike in shell, it's perfectly safe to use `>` both times. [See here.](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Redirection)

Comment: ThanksNow what to add to this printing comand line so that I can print the Total number of the lines
SO I would like these two results printed in the same output file
"awk '{print \$2 > \"test.txt\"}' $fname");
"awk 'END {print NR > \"test.txt\"}' $fname")

Comment: ThanksNow what to add to this printing comand line so that I can print the Total number of the lines SO I would like these two results printed in the same output file "awk '{print \$2 > \"test.txt\"}' $fname"); "awk 'END {print NR > \"test.txt\"}' $fname")